# jqGrid: checkbox column not reading proper json data from server

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

```
grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "json",
    url: "Industry.aspx/GetAllRecords",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'POST',
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    serializeGridData: function (posData) {
        //alert(JSON.stringify(posData.d));
        return JSON.stringify(posData);
    },
    colNames: ['', 'Code', 'Description', 'Description2', 'Active'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'action', index: 'action', width: 45, sortable: false },
        { name: 'IndustryCd', width: 80 },
        { name: 'IndustryDs', width: 200 },
        { name: 'IndustryDs2', width: 200 },
        { name: 'active', width: 50,
            editoptions: { value: '1:0' },
            formatter: 'checkbox', formatoptions: { disabled: false}
        }
    ],
    height: 'auto',
    gridview: true,
    loadonce: false,
    id:'IndustryCd',
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: function (obj) {
            alert(obj.d);
            return typeof obj.d === "string" ? $.parseJSON(obj.d) : obj.d;
        },
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
    },
    loadComplete: function () {

    }
});
```

JSON data

```
d=[
  {
    "IndustryCd": "1",
    "IndustryDs": "Manufacture",
    "IndustryDs2": "",
    "Active": true
  },
  {
    "IndustryCd": "2",
    "IndustryDs": "Sales",
    "IndustryDs2": "",
    "Active": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: You question doesn't contain any question at all. Also, describe what's the expected and what's the actual behavior, please.

Answer (score 1):

I see some problems in the code/data:

1. JavaScript is case sensitive. You have to use the same names in `colModel` and in the input data (compare `"Active": true` and `"Active": false` with `name: 'active'` in `colModel`).
2. You specified `editoptions: { value: '1:0' }`, but you use `true` and `false` in the input data instead of the values `1` and `0`.
3. You used `id:'IndustryCd',` as the option of jqGrid. Correct place would be inside of `jsonReader` instead.
4. Your input data don't contains any paging information. Thus I can suppose that you don't implemented server side paging of data. You should use `loadonce: true` to inform jqGrid that it should load the whole data and to make local paging.
5. You create the grid which contains no `pager` or `toppager` parameter. You don't wrote in the question *which version of jqGrid and which fork of jqGrid you use*. If you don't use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork then the default value `rowNum: 20` could be set and one will see only the first 20 rows returned from the server. The user will have no possibility to change the page and to display the rest of the data. You should add `rowNum` with some large enough value (like `rowNum: 10000`) if you can't upgrade to free jqGrid.
6. You use `formatter: 'checkbox', formatoptions: { disabled: false}`, which is origin of many misunderstanding. The user will see checkboxes which can be changes, but your current code don't process in any way the changes. The formatter have no relation with editing of the grid. Thus the changes will be not saved even if you would use some editing mode later.